# Sort two-dimensional array based on ranks from a different two-dimensional array

Tags: numpy, scipy.stats

I have two two-dimensional numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats.rankdata

arr_data = np.array( [[0.3, 0.1, 0.7, 0.5], [0.1, 0.5, 0.4, 0.07]] )
weights = np.array( [[0.05, 0.1, 0.35, 0.5], [0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.3]] )
```

I need to sort both of them based on one common ranking. The common ranks are generated from values in the first array along axis=1:

```
ranks = scipy.stats.rankdata(arr_data, axis=1).astype(int)
print('data', arr_data)
print('ranks',ranks)
```

The obtained ranks are as follows:

```
[[2 1 4 3]
 [2 4 3 1]]
```

I'm stuck with how to proceed to obtain the following sorted arrays:

```
for arr_data: [[0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7], [0.07, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5]]
for weights: [[0.1, 0.05, 0.5, 0.35], [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4]]
```

i.e., my weighs are sorted based on data-array ranking. Ultimately, I want to multiply the data with their corresponding weights keeping the order of the sorted values from the data array. In my project, I have very large datasets so I'd like to avoid Python lists and looping.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is an elegant solution:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[0.3, 0.1, 0.7, 0.5], [0.1, 0.5, 0.4, 0.07]])
weights = np.array([[0.05, 0.1, 0.35, 0.5], [0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.3]])

ranks = np.argsort(data, axis=1)
sorted_data = np.take_along_axis(data, ranks, axis=1)
sorted_weights = np.take_along_axis(weights, ranks, axis=1)
print('data\n', data)
print('weights\n', weights)
print("sorted data\n",sorted_data)
print("sorted weights\n", sorted_weights)
```